# sort on alphanumeric column of datatable clir

Tags: sorting, jsp, datatables

I have a problem in sorting on a clir inea datatable except that the datatable component that of it uses custumized js functions to do the sorting and never takes alphanumerics into account.

I tried to properly sort the stakes column (I was implementing an algorithm ) except that I noticed that this one overwrites the normal operation of the component which allows sorting for the other columns of the table.

there is any solution on clir datatable for sorting alphanumerics column??

Here is descending and ascending sorting

[image]

Comment: There are various questions on Stack Overflow showing how to sort a column of "numbers as strings" (including numbers formatted as currency) in numeric order. Here is a list: [how to sort currency columns](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatable+sort+currency+column+site%253Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: If none of those helped, you can [edit] your question and describe why they were not helpful, and also provide a [mre] showing your specific problem. You can also take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance on asking a good question - one which is more likely to receive helpful answers.